# Creating META tag using PHP in wordpress HEAD crashes site

Tags: php, wordpress, head

I am trying to add PHP to the HEAD in Wordpress to create a META tag. I tried the code as simple PHP in headers.php or in funtions.php. Either way it crashes my entire site. In funtions.php is used the folowing:

```
function get_my_meta_keywords() {
    // make sure post 
    if(is_singular( 'post' ) == TRUE)
    {
     $ID = get_the_ID();
     // validate ID
     if($ID != FALSE)
     {
         $meta_catagory = get_the_category($ID);
         $asize = count($meta_catagory);
         // make sure array is not empty
         if($asize > 0)
         {
          $category_string = ""; 
          for($i = 0; $i < $asize; $i++)
          { 
             $category_string = $category_string.$meta_catagory[$i]->name;
             // add comma to end of string only if another category is in array
             if($i != $asize - 1)
             {
                 $category_string = $category_string.',';
             }
          }
          // 
          echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$category_string;.'">'; 
         }
     }
    }                    }

add_action( 'wp_head', 'get_my_meta_keywords');
```

In headers.php I used:

```
    <?php       
    if(is_singular( 'post' ) == TRUE)
    {
     $ID = get_the_ID();
     // validate ID
     if($ID != FALSE)
     {
         $meta_catagory = get_the_category($ID);
         $asize = count($meta_catagory);
         // make sure array is not empty
         if($asize > 0)
         {
          $category_string = ""; 
          for($i = 0; $i < $asize; $i++)
          { 
             $category_string = $category_string.$meta_catagory[$i]->name;
             // add comma to end of string only if another category is in array
             if($i != $asize - 1)
             {
                 $category_string = $category_string.',';
             }
          }
          // 
          echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$category_string;.'">'; 
         }
     }
    }                    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed is this line:

```
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$category_string;.'">';
```

It has a semi colon after the variable name. It should be like this:

```
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$category_string.'">';
```

Second thing I noticed is that, the header code contains an extra closing curly braces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Yep it was the semi colon. The extra curly brace was actually a remnant while posting the code on the this website. I was having so many problems with insert code not including the last line so I did a copy paste from the function and forgot to clean it up. My bad.

Comment: @iggy_pop That's cool. Hope you got everything resolved now! If my answer helped you in resolving your problem, please mark it as the selected answer.